# redux state gets wrapped in another object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to create a sample app using React Native & Redux. What I am not able to understand is that why my state object is getting wrapped into another object.

I have **initial state** as *{email: 'test'}*. I have to access email as *this.props.email.email*
Why do I have to do this.props.email.email instead of this.props.email

Any help will be appreciated.

**Welcome.js**

```js
class Welcome extends Component {
  render() {  
    return (
      <View style={ styles.container }>
        <View style = { styles.inputContainer }>
          <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.props.email)}</Text>
          <Button title = 'Update Email' 
              style = { styles.placeButton }
              onPress={() => this.props.onChangeEmail('hello')}
          />
          </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    email: state.email
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onChangeEmail: (email) => { dispatch({type: 'CHANGE_EMAIL_INPUT', email: email}) }
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Welcome)
```

**EmailReducer.js**

```js
const initialState = {
  email: 'test',
};

const emailReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE_EMAIL_INPUT':
     return Object.assign({}, state,  
                { email: action.email }
            );
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default emailReducer;
```

**Store.js**

```js
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import emailReducer from '../reducers/EmailReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  email: emailReducer
});

const configureStore = () => {
  return createStore(rootReducer);
}

export default configureStore;
```

Comment: How are you connecting mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps and your Welcome component?

Comment: Hi @Keilath ,updated the code. i thought there's only one way of connecting so I omitted the connect line.

Comment: can you share your code where you create the store?  usually the name of the reducer becomes the key in the global state object that you access its state from.

Comment: That was correct, I think the problem is in the creation of the store. Which reducer are you passing to createStore?

Comment: @DavinTryon updated the code for store

Comment: So, in your current set up you would get the value of email: `state.email.email` because you are storing your `emailReducer` state on a key named `email`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call combineReducers you are creating a store with the following shape

```
{
  email: {
    email: 'test'
  }
}
```

That is, the keys in the object passed to combineReducers are the root keys of the state object. The initial state for the email reducer is inserted in the key "email" of the state object.

This is the reason why you need to write this.props.email.email: the former is the key in the root state object (that deduced from combineReducers), the latter is the prop of the state part managed by emailReducer